# Integral and mean value theorem question

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $X = \mathbb{S}^{p-1}\times [0,1]$ and let $f,g,\lambda : X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ three continuous functions My question is whether or not there exists $x_{0}\in X$ such that
$$
\int_{X}\cfrac{1}{1+\lambda(x)}f(x) + \cfrac{\lambda(x)}{1+\lambda(x)}g(x) dx = \cfrac{1}{1+\lambda(x_{0})}\int_{X}f(x)dx + \cfrac{\lambda(x_{0})}{1+\lambda(x_{0})}\int_{X}g(x)dx.
$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $d x$ the Riemannian volume form on $X$? Also, do you have more assumption on $\lambda$? Since if $\lambda$ is allowed to be close to $-1$ then you could have integrability issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda(x) = -1$ for some $x \in X$, then no. Otherwise,

Let $$r = \frac 1{1+\lambda}$$
Your integral equation becomes
$$\begin{align}\int_X r(x)f(x)+(1-r(x))g(x)\,dx &= r(x_0)\int_Xf(x)\,dx + (1-r(x_0))\int_xg(x)\,dx\\\int_Xg(x)\,dx + \int_Xr(x)(f(x) - g(x))\,dx &=\int_Xg(x)\,dx + r(x_0)\int_Xf(x) - g(x)\,dx
\\\int_Xr(x)(f(x) - g(x))\,dx &= r(x_0)\int_Xf(x) - g(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Since $r$ is continuous on the compact set $X$, it has a minimum value $m$ and maximum value $M$. So
$$m\int_Xf(x) - g(x)\,dx\le\int_Xr(x)(f(x) - g(x))\,dx\le M\int_Xf(x) - g(x)\,dx$$
$$m \le \dfrac{\int_Xr(x)(f(x) - g(x))\,dx}{\int_Xf(x) - g(x)\,dx} \le M$$

Since $X$ is path-connected, there is some curve $\gamma$ with $r(\gamma(0)) = m$ and $r(\gamma(1)) = M$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is some $t \in [0,1]$ with $r(\gamma(t)) = \frac{\int_Xr(x)(f(x) - g(x))\,dx}{\int_Xf(x) - g(x)\,dx}$.

Setting $x_0 = \gamma(t)$ gives the result you are after.